# Returning columns containing maximum values across all the variables in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

```
zone_id=1:6
v1=c(12,22,31,12,5,17)
v2=c(15,22,28,16,18,21)
v3=c(18,10,14,9,10,17)
v4=c(20,3,2,5,12,21)
mydata=data.frame(zone_id,v1,v2,v3,v4)
```

I have a dataframe a crude model of which can be made using the above code. It consists of rows of data relating to geographical areas. I have variables (4 in this example, but 69 in my actual dataset)  which contain integers which are observations in those areas.
For each zone_id I want to identify the variable from V1 to V4 which contains the maximum value.  Where there is a tie I want to return the names of each of the variables that contain the tied maximum value. So for zone 1, I want to return V4, for zone 2 I want to return V1 and V2 and so on.

I am very new to R and have been unable to get to first base with this. I've explored R help files and thought there may be a solution using sweep? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `which(x == max(x))` idiom here and use `apply()` to run this against each row:

```
apply(mydata[, -1], 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))
```

which gives:

```
> apply(mydata[, -1], 1, function(x) which(x == max(x)))
[[1]]
v4 
 4 

[[2]]
v1 v2 
 1  2 

[[3]]
v1 
 1 

[[4]]
v2 
 2 

[[5]]
v2 
 2 

[[6]]
v2 v4 
 2  4
```

The list contains the vectors of indices of the variable(s) that are maximal, and the names of those vectors can be extracted using `names()` to give the actual variable ID:

```
> out <- apply(mydata[, -1], 1,  function(x) which(x == max(x)))
> names(out[[2]])
[1] "v1" "v2"
> lapply(out, names)
[[1]]
[1] "v4"

[[2]]
[1] "v1" "v2"

[[3]]
[1] "v1"

[[4]]
[1] "v2"

[[5]]
[1] "v2"

[[6]]
[1] "v2" "v4"
```

If your data might contain `NA` then we need to be a little bit more clever, e.g.

```
apply(mydata[, -1], 1, 
      function(x, na.rm = FALSE)
          which(x == max(x, na.rm = na.rm)),
      na.rm = TRUE)
```

wherein we can pass in whether to ignore the `NA` or not.

Comment: I think there is a which.max function which is equivalent to which(x == max(x)), this would make to code even shorter.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra The reason I didn't go with `which.max()` is that the OP wanted all indices returning if there were tied maximal values. `which.max()` returns the **first** maximum encountered, which is where it and the `which(x == max(x))` version differ. To be exact, `which.max(x)` is *only* equivalent to `which(x == max(x))` where there are no ties in `x`.

Comment: Both these answers return the data I need, thanks very much to both of you. By way of a spupplimentary question, is there a way to return them as a table? These data will be needed for a separate set of analyses.

Comment: @roman, looks quite addictive. And R I did not spot a lot of R yet. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @gavinr Not simply, you'd need to pad the list components with `NA`s up to length of longest component. Doable, but depends on what you wanted to do with them later. You are probably better off leaving the list as is and applying these separate analysis over the list. Ask another Q if you want help with that.

Comment: @GavinSimpson. Thanks Gavin. The ties are going to be entered into an algorithm which will nudge them into one category or another depending on the results of a further piece of modelling. I was going to knife and fork it using a bunch of SQL queries (not being a programmer myself), as the original data are from a database, but I guess I should try to do the whole thing in R - although as my initiation into the language, it's going to be a bit of a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `rank`. Note the minus sign before the data as the default ordering is low->high

```
x <- apply(-mydata[,-1],1,rank,ties.method="min")
x
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
v1    4    1    1    2    4    3
v2    3    1    2    1    1    1
v3    2    3    3    3    3    3
v4    1    4    4    4    2    1
```

And you could extract the names with `sapply`:

```
sapply(mydata$zone_id,function(y) rownames(x)[x[,y]==1])
[[1]]
[1] "v4"

[[2]]
[1] "v1" "v2"

[[3]]
[1] "v1"

[[4]]
[1] "v2"

[[5]]
[1] "v2"

[[6]]
[1] "v2" "v4"
```